# Add a newline after each XML tag

Tags: xml, awk, tags

My xml file looks like this:

```
<price = "2.22"><instock = "1">
```

I need to have it like that:

```
<price = "2.22">
<instock = "1">
```

After each ">" character I need to put a newline character with awk or sed.
How can i accomplish that?
thank you

Comment: I'm not sure `<price = "2.22">` is valid XML.

Answer (score 2):

As KeithB said, there are potential problems that can arise from using a crude approach. However, this crude approach is a tiny bit more selective so that chances it will fail are reduced by about 0.00001% which may be enough.

```
sed 's|><|>\n<|g' inputfile
```

If there may be whitespace between the angle brackets, then this may be better:

```
sed 's|>[[:space:]]*<|>\n<|g' inputfile
```

which will eliminate that whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this right, you need something more powerful than awk.  One of the problems is awk won't handle `>` inside strings or comments.  You might be better off with perl or python.  If this is just to make a file easier to look at visually, it might be fine.

A quick and dirty awk script is

```
 awk '{for(i=1; i<= NF-1; i++) printf "%s>\n",$i}' FS='>'
```

This treats `>` as the separator between fields, and prints out each on its own line.  Its pretty crude, but might be a starting place.